# Remove characters between different parameters

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string of different emails

> ex: "email1@uy.com, email2@iu.it, email3@uu.edu"  etc, etc

I would like to formulate a Regex that creates the following output

> ex: "email1,email2,email3"  etc, etc

How can I remove characters between an "@" and "," but leaving a "," and a Space  in C#

Thank you so much for the help!!

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166855/c-sharp-preg-replace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to replace all characters between @ and comma by blank, the easiest option is to use `Regex.Replace`:

```
var emails = "a@m.com, b@m.com, d@m.com";
var result = Regex.Replace(emails, "@[^,]+", string.Empty);
// result is "a, b, d"
```

Please note that it leaves spaces after comma in the result, as you wanted in your question, though your example result has spaces removed.

The regular expression looks for all substrings starting '@' characters, followed by any character which is not comma. Those substrings are replaced with empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing all occurrences of `@[^,]+` with an empty string will do the job.

The expression matches sequences that start in `@`, inclusive, up to a comma or to the end, exclusive. Therefore, commas in the original string of e-mails would be kept.

[Demo.](https://regex101.com/r/pV4kE6/1)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't need to use a regex, in that case you can do the following:

```
string input = "email1@uy.com, email2@iu.it, email3@uu.edu";

 input = input.Replace(" ", "");
 string[] ocurrences = input.Split(',');

 for (int i = 0; i < ocurrences.Length; i++)
 {
     string s = ocurrences[i];
     ocurrences[i] = s.Substring(0, s.IndexOf('@'));
 }

 string final = string.Join(", ", occurences);
```

Comment: `ocurrences.Aggregate((a, b) => a + "," + b)` can be done as `string.Join(",", ocurrences)`.

Comment: indeed! I forgot the string.Join. The answer has been edited! Thank you