# Converting Wordpress sanitize filename function from PHP to C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, regex

I'm trying to convert Wordpress `sanitize_file_name` function from PHP to C# so I can use it to generate unicode slugs for my site's articles on a web app that build myself.

**This is my class:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Web;

 namespace MyProject.Helpers
{
 public static class Slug
 {

    public static string SanitizeFileName(string filename)
    {

        string[] specialChars = { "?", "[", "]", "/", "\\", "=", "< ", "> ", ":", ";", ",", "'", "\"", "& ", "$", "#", "*", "(", ")", "|", "~", "`", "!", "{", "}" };

        filename = MyStrReplace(filename, specialChars, "");
        filename = Regex.Replace(filename, @"/[\s-]+/", "-");

        filename.TrimEnd('-').TrimStart('-');
        filename.TrimEnd('.').TrimStart('.');
        filename.TrimEnd('_').TrimStart('_');


        return filename;
    }

    private static string MyStrReplace(string strToCheck, string[] strToReplace, string newValue)
    {
        foreach (string s in strToReplace)
        {
            strToCheck = strToCheck.Replace(s, newValue);
        }
        return strToCheck;
    }

   // source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166855/c-sharp-preg-replace

    public static string PregReplace(string input, string[] pattern, string[] replacements)
    {
        if (replacements.Length != pattern.Length)
            throw new ArgumentException("Replacement and Pattern Arrays must be balanced");

        for (int i = 0; i < pattern.Length; i++)
        {
            input = Regex.Replace(input, pattern[i], replacements[i]);
        }

        return input;
    }
 }
}
```

I put a title like: `"let's say that I have --- in there what to do"` but I get the same results only with the single apostrophe trimmed (let's -> lets), nothing else changed.

I want the same equivalent conversion as Wordpress'. Using ASP.NET 4.5 / C#

Comment: Do not use regex delimiters in C#. Remove `/` from the pattern.

Comment: @stribizhev yep, I removed it and it seems to work. I'll test it again to make sure that the function as a whole works as intended. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since in C#  you do not have action modifiers, there are no regex delimiters.

The solution is simply to remove `/` symbols from the pattern:

```
filename = Regex.Replace(filename, @"[\s-]+", "-");
                                    ^      ^
```

Comment: Works great. Thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: It said 59 seconds, so I went to eat :) I wouldn't forget. Thanks again